# "Slugger" meaning in this context

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

I heard a woman called a man "*Slugger*".

My dictionary says:

> a baseball player who hits the ball a very long way

It seems that It's used metaphorically. What's that supposed to mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to ask one of them to know for sure.

It sounds like a *pet name* (defined by NOAD as, "a name that is used instead of someone's usual first name to express fondness or familiarity"). Many pet names are tied to sweetness (*Honey, Sugar, Sweetheart*, etc.), but some less common ones can be tied to sports (*Slugger, Champ, Sport*, etc.).

You never know where a pet name might come from. Sometimes there's a special meaning, sometimes there isn't. I once met a man who called his wife "Loveboat", and I once worked with a man whose wife called him "Pumpkin". Sometimes it's best not to ask; like a magician's secret, some things are better left unexplained.